# Summa Cum Laude - Tile and Error

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

For any set X, {X} denotes the sum of its elements. "I divide {A}" means all items in that set are divisors of the sum of A's elements.
Arrange the tiles so that four are in each set and the rules are obeyed. I made this up myself.
[image: Problem #12: a three-way Venn diagram with the numbers 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, and 10 to be placed. The top left section says "{A} & I divide {A}". The top right section says "{A} & I divide {C}". The bottom section says "{C} and {C} > {A}"]

Comment: What are I, A, and C?   What do you mean by "{C} and {C}>{A}" and how is that different to just "{C}>{A}"? Since {A} always divides {A}, what does "{A}&I divide {A}" mean, and how is it different to just "I divides {A}"?

Comment: Apologies if unclear: The first {} tells you the sum of the associated set (i.e. the one next to the statement.  The term after the "&" is extra information about either the set or its elements

Comment: So making it properly clear:  the elements of the top-left set sum to a number {A} and each element divides {A}.  The sum of the top-right set also sums to the same number {A}, but its elements all divide {C}.  And what is {C} that is the sum of the bottom set, and additionally we are told that {C} is bigger than {A}

Comment: My dv is purely for the presentation. If you want to convey the message "These add up to X", the best way to do that is to write "These add up to X" on the diagram. The given notation, even with the explanation, is completely incomprehensible: if {A} is the sum of some unknown group A, why is it mentioned in two places? If it's meant to refer to the group in the nearest ellipse, why does it say {A} at both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

As

> 1 + 2 + 6 + 9 = 18, and 1,2,6,9 all divide 18 so {A} = 18
> 1 + 2 + 7 + 10 = 20, and {C} = 20
> 1 + 2 + 5 + 10 = 18 = {A} and 1,2,5,10 all divide 20 aka {C}